# How to get the value in realtime in nuxt js observable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a NuxtJS project. For getting the current screen width in real-time, I created an instance variable based on [Accessing screen width in vue components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595804/accessing-screen-width-in-vue-components) and [“window is not defined” in Nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979644/window-is-not-defined-in-nuxt-js).

But, the value is not getting updated in real-time. Either there is a delay or I need to refresh. I just need only the current screen width if it is less than 500px it should be true or false.

`plugins/breakpoints.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$isMobile = Vue.observable(window.innerWidth < 600)

window.addEventListener(
  'resize',
  () => (Vue.prototype.$isMobile = window.innerWidth < 600)
)
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [{ src: './plugins/breakpoints', ssr: false }],
```

`pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>isMobile {{ $isMobile }}</h1>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',
}
</script>
```

CodeSandBox(for quick preview): https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-stitch-1sdh6r

Comment: You're using [this module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module) here? Also, what is the end goal in your case? Can't you achieve the same result with bare CSS? `ssr: false` should be `mode: 'client'` btw.

Comment: Not using `device-module` (don't know if it is built-in). My end goal is there are some pages where I am conditionally rendering based on the isMobile property. If it is related to CSS only, yea I know we can use @media query, and when applying `mode: 'client'` is not working either